# How to fetch the username list in listview in Android from Firebase database?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have registered and saved users through my app and now I want to fetch the list of usernames as shown below from Firebase database. How do I do it in list view? my database is shown below:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<MODELCLASSNAME> Users=new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference df=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
df.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapShot user : dataSnapshot.getchildren()){

          Users.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(MODELCLASSNAME.class));

      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
//Now loop through your arraylist
```

Comment: i get error at this line(for(DataSnapShot user : dataSnapshot){) saying (foreach not applicable to type 'com.google.firebase.database.Datasnapshot') what should i do ?

Comment: Ok instead of for each loop make a hashmap of type 
<String,ModelClassName> equate that with dataSnaphot.getValue()

Answer (score 1):

get your database reference

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mPostDb = firebaseDatabase.getReference("User");
```

Now query your table

```
Query query = mPostDb.orderByKey();
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapShot user : dataSnapshot){
                // Do what ever you whatever you want with this user object 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
public void retrieveNames() {

    Query myQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("name").equalTo("INSERT-HERE-A-NAME-FOR-YOUR-SEARCH");

    myQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
//FOR YOUR DATA STRUCTURE -
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String image_uri = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
                String name = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
                String username = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
                YourUserObject User = new YourUserObject  (image_uri, name, username);

                YourArrayList.add(User);

            }
            YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

            @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```